# How do I set the label for an intent's output in the shortcut creator?

Tags: swift, sirishortcuts, appintents

I'm creating a custom intent using the AppIntents framework. I've set up my intent to return a result with some data so I can use it in other shortcuts. When I use the output result as the input to another action, it shows the `title` field as the output:

```swift
struct MyIntent: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "This is the title"
    static var description = IntentDescription("This is the description.")
    
    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        Summary("This is the parameter summary")
    }
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        return .result(value: true)
    }
}
```

[image: First action: "This is the parameter summary"; second action: "If (This is the title)"]

The title field is also used in the list of possible actions, so I'd like to keep it as is. However, I don't like the look of the description being used for the output result (in this case, the "If (This is the title)" part). I can see with other built-in actions that it's possible to set these separately; for example, the "Match Text" action lists "Matches" as the output. Is there a way to change just the output label while leaving the title the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the result value name in the `IntentDescription` initializer, new in iOS 17:

```
import AppIntents

@available(iOS 17.0, *)
struct MyIntent: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "This is the title"
    static var description = IntentDescription("This is the description.", resultValueName: "My Result")
    
    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        Summary("This is the parameter summary")
    }
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & ReturnsValue<Bool> {
        return .result(value: true)
    }
}
```

[image: Shortcuts screenshot]